# How can I hide JMeter setup thread group samplers to be reported in the generated dashboard?

Tags: performance, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a setup thread group to generate some test data and clear previously generated data from previous runs. This setup thread group contains hundreds of samplers. I have an issue that this setup thread group samplers appear in the generated dashboard report after the run completes. I want to hide them from the generated dashboard. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are following options:

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) to the setUp Thread Group (the same level as all your Samplers) and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   prev.setIgnore()
   ```

   this will call [SampleResult.setIgnore() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setIgnore--) instructing JMeter to discard all Sample Results in the JSR223 PreProcessor's [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setIgnore--) so they won't appear in the [Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) and [.jtl result file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles)
2. There is [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) (installable via [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)) it provides possibility to remove sample results which names match certain pattern from the .jtl results file. Alternatively you can provide an offset in seconds to cut sample results from the beginning (or the end) of the .jtl results file
3. [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) provides the same functionality, moreover you can generate various tables and charts in non-GUI mode